# socket.io get socket by using custom added field

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io in my node.js project.
I'm using custom login event for login. when user login, I save userID into the socket.
what I want is access this socket using this userID field. I can access the socket using socket id.

```
//save user id     
socket.on('login',(userID)=>{
     socket.userID = userID 
})

//also I can access socket using socket id like this
var socketOB = io.sockets.connected[socketID]
```

but I want to get the socket using userID which I stored when user login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage an object of sockets like this:

```
var allSockets = {};


socket.on('login',(userID)=>{
    allSockets[userID] = socket; 
})

socket.on('logout', (userID)=>{
  delete allSockets[userID];
});
```

where the userID is the key and socket is the value.

```
{
  "someUserId" : socketObject,
  "anotherUsedId": socketObject
}
```

Comment: yeah this method is good. nut i got 1 little problem. when i have the socket, how can i remove that field form 'allSockets' using socket details. (without having userID)

Comment: Socket io generate for each socket client a unique id, so every integration with this socket you can simply use this id to identify the socket and manipulate it. You can use allSockets as array of sockets, on new connection you push the socket to the array and on disconnection you remove it using splice. To get the current socket use: let found = allSockets.find(s=>s.id ==socket.id);